# Razor @page routing to a different page

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I'm using aspnet core 3.

In a controller, my user can type in a single url like ... /login ... and then I test which company it is and return the correct view - like this:

```
[Route("login")]
public IActionResult Login()
{
    return _company == "a" ? View("ThisView") : View("ThatView");
}
```

But if I use Razor routing ... @page "/login" ... how can I do the same? I need the user to type a single url, but then I need to test which company it is and then direct to the correct razor page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can use "[RedirectToPageResult()](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/action-results)"  in razor page to return to
>   the corresponding page instead of view.
>
> The premise is that you need to create the corresponding page to
>   return.

For example, I have a page named MyTest, user can input the parameter in this page.

If user enter "a" , then return to ThisPage.cshtml, otherwise, return to  ThatPage.cshtml.

MyTest.cshtml:

```html
@page
@model WebApplication1_rzaor_page.MyTestModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "MyTest";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>MyTest</h1>
<form asp-page-handler="Login" method="post">
    <input id="Text1" type="text" name="_company" />
    <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

MyTest.cshtml.cs:

```
 public class MyTestModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet()
    { 
    } 
    public IActionResult OnPostLogin(string _company)
    {
        return _company == "a" ? new RedirectToPageResult("ThisPage") : new RedirectToPageResult("ThatPage"); 
    }
}
```

Here is the result :

[image]